# Showing calls from an internal function

Tags: plantuml

I want to depict something like

```
A::foo() { //public API
    internal();
}

A::internal() {
    B.bar()
}
```

So I tried

```
->A: foo()
A -> A :internal()
A -> B :bar()
```

But I end up with something like

```
     ,-.             ,-.      
     |A|             |B|      
     `+'             `+'      
 foo()|               |       
 ----->               |       
      |               |       
      |----.                  
      |    | internal()       
      |<---'                  
      |               |       
      |     bar()     |       
      | -------------->       
     ,+.             ,+.      
     |A|             |B|      
     `-'             `-'
```

Which rather ends up denoting that `bar()` is invoked *after* completion of `internal`. How do I get the call to `bar()` to show up from *within* `internal()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can show this with activation boxes:

```
->A: foo()
activate A
A -> A :internal()
activate A
A -> B :bar()
activate B
deactivate B
deactivate A
deactivate A
```

[image]